# To find the displacement of a rolling body

Tags: kinematics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, relative-motion, equations-of-motion

When calculating the displacement of a rolling body do we just calculate the displacement due to Vcom in a particular time t or additionally need to consider also the displacement that may be produced because of the rolling motion.

Answer (score 1):

For pure rolling (i.e., rolling without slipping) the displacement of the center of mass (COM) ***is*** due to the rolling motion. They are not independent.

For pure rolling the linear velocity of the center of mass $v_{COM}$ is related to the angular velocity $\omega$, where $R$ is the radius of the rolling body, by

$$v_{com}=R\omega$$

Where $\omega$ is in radians per second.

Thus

$$v_{com}t=R\omega t$$

For example, if $\omega= 2\pi$ radians per second, after 1 second the angular displacement is $2\pi$ radians and the linear displacement of the COM is $2\pi R$, or the circumference of the rolling body.

Hope this helps.